# Do not show certain fields in admin page

Tags: python, django

In Django, you get the model editor for free in the `admin/` pages. This all works fine, but I have a few fields in my models that are generated and should never be touched by anybody through a form.

How can I exclude them from these `admin/.../change/` forms?

I added exclude to the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class exampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('field',)

class example(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Comment: Setting `exclude` is the right way to do this. You haven't shown your code so it's difficult to tell why it isn't working.

Comment: @Alasdair I added code

Comment: The updated code still looks ok. How are you registering the model admin class?

Comment: @Alasdair should the code all go into `models.py` ?

Comment: Is your `exampleAdmin` registered?

Comment: @4140tm no, where / how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a few fields in my models that are
>   generated and should never be touched by anybody through a form.

You may also use [`editable=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#editable) on your model's field

> **[Field.editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#editable)**
>
> If False, the field **will not be displayed in the admin or any other
>   ModelForm**. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is
>   True.

```
class Example(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=False)
```

Comment: Yes, the field still works with your code, just won't be visible/editable e.g. on the admin

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution, because less code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `register` your `exampleAdmin` to take effect. In your `admin.py` add `admin.site.register(example, exampleAdmin)`